# I have made an app which adds an image to a list using another activity, but when I return to the main one, nothing is saved

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Pressing an "Add Image" button in the main activity starts another "Input Photo" activity. I upload the photo to the "Input Photo" activity and click submit. When clicked, submit just passes the photo using .putExtra and then calls finish(). Then the flow is returned to the main activity, where the function update() updates the ListView:

```
private void updateLists(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String imageFromInput = intent.getStringExtra("imageFromInput");

        if(imageFromInput != null){
            Uri imageFromInputURI = Uri.parse(imageFromInput);
 
            listOfImages.add(imageFromInputURI);
        }
    }
```

The update() function is called in the button "Add Image" listener.

This is the listener:

```
buttonAddPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InputPicture.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                updateLists();
                customBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

The thing is, if I start a new main activity using startActivity() from the "Input Photo" activity, the main activity updates and shows the good ListView. Why the ListView updates only when I start a new instance of the main activity?

Comment: You are talking twice about an update() function. Which i do not see.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use start activity for result. The onclick listener does not have access to the activity it is staring
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

```
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent intent = result.getData();
                        //get your image string here
                    }
                }
            });
```

Launch Activity

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputPicture.class);
activityResultLauncher.launch(myintent);
```

Activity which returns

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
//set your image data to intent here
activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
activity.finish();
```